# Openshift - when cloning existing app, updating files on `~/.env/user_vars` raises `Permission denied`

Tags: deployment, openshift-online-2, cloning

after cloning the existing openshift app using
`rhc app create dev --from-app sample/live`, I push the repo to execute the `build`.

Then it raises an error while building.

**server reponse:**

```
...
~/.env/user_vars/APP_ENV: Permission denied
...
... Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute action hook 'deploy' ...
```

**deploy hook command:** that triggers the error

```
if [ "$(type -t set_env_var)" == "function" ]; then
  set_env_var 'APP_ENV' $APP_ENV $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/.env/user_vars
  set_env_var 'APP_DEBUG' $APP_DEBUG $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/.env/user_vars
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

**tldr:** delete and recreate the files

**Cause:** when we clone an existing openshift app, Openshift is the one that writes the files on `~.env/user_vars/` directory. Thus will have the `root` as the owner.

**To solve it**, I need to change the owner of these files.

Since `chown` and `chmod` could not be used, we will **delete and recreate the file**. Luckily we have the delete permission. :)